# How to fix N: Skipping acquire of configured file

Tags: pantheon-terminal

terminal:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

result:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                   
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                   
Get:3 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease [5,909 B]                            
Get:4 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [292 kB]            
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Get:8 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,473 B]                           
Hit:9 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Hit:10 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                 
Hit:11 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                               
Fetched 300 kB in 22s (13.5 kB/s)                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

Answer (score 0):

[VSCode issue #114137](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114137) appears to be the problem.
It looks like only the new repository location has the `arm64` and `armhf` packages, so updating the URL should fix the warnings.
The repository's URL has changed from `http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode` to `http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code` as described in [issue #112223](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112223).
To fix this, update the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list` to point to the new location as shown below.

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main"
```